# Why is my success function being skipped?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a form that displays results based on what dropdowns options are chosen. The choices will need to be updated somewhat regularly so we are opting to bring in the data in through a hosted JSON file, as it's easy to go from CSV to JSON for us. I have written the following in hopes of getting the file and parsing the options for use in my dropdowns.

```
$.ajax(
  {
    url: '---/DeptData.json',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data)
    {
      //iterate over the data and append a selet option
      $.each(data, function(key, val)
      {
        var option = $('<option id="' + val.DeptID + '">' + val.DeptDescr + '</option>');
        $('#DeptSelect').append(option);
      })
    },
    error:function()
    {
      //if there is an error append a 'none avaliable' option
      $('#DeptSelect').append('<option id="-1">NONE AVAILABLE</option>');
    }
  })
```

The goal is to have it parsed so that I can use the following line within my functions.

```
var id = $('#DeptSelect').val()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure `data` is non-empty?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is the `error` handler (which has **three** parameters/arguments) executed?

Comment: Please use this line:  `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) `

and console.log. all three variables within the function. this could help find the error.

Comment: I was able to remove the dataType, and tried a modified/updated version of my JSON file. I believe it was because of the original hierarchy had another key which then referenced the values I wanted, within the JSON. Thank you for the help.